# Configure Python Path in Visual Studio Code with venv running from bash on Windows

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, windows-subsystem-for-linux, virtual-environment

I have a virtual environment set up inside bash for Windows (Ubuntu) and VS Code installed (Windows). The Python project runs well inside the venv in bash but I would like to now debug it through Visual Code.

I'm trying to set the python.pythonPath as follows inside settings.json

```
{
    "python.pythonPath": "C:\\repos\\myrepo\\venv\\bin\\python"
}
```

The error returned is "Please validate the path ..."

Note that through bash for Windows, the filesystem is accessible through /mnt/c/

As for the auto-detection of Python, it only lists the python.exe installed on the windows filesystem (which is of no use to me).

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments explains that doing this should be sufficient but doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because WSL isn't officially supported yet by the extension as of version 0.8.0. See https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-python/issues/67 to up-vote and track the issue for detecting WSL-based virtual environments.

Comment: Any update on this? I've set my python path: "python.pythonPath": "env/bin/python" in settings.json, but I'm still getting strange lint errors that aren't actual problems, I think the path still might not be setup properly

Comment: We support WSL via the Remote - WSL extension (and I personally use it all the time). If you're getting linting errors then your environment is being picked up in order to run the linter.

Comment: I was able to get it working.  I think I was missing the WSL remote extension.